# DPDK Hash failing to lookup data from secondary process

Tags: hash, dpdk

Failing to use existing rte Hash from secondary process:

```
  h = rte_hash_find_existing("some_hash");
  if (h) {
        // this will work, in case we re-create
        //rte_hash_free(h);
    }
    else {
         h = rte_hash_create (&params);
    }
  // using the hash will crash the process with:
  // Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  ret = rte_hash_lookup_data (h,name,&data);
```

DPDK Version: dpdk-19.02

Build Mode Static: CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=n

The Primary and secondary processes are different binaries but linked to the same DPDK library

The Key is added in primary as follows

```
struct cdev_key {
    uint64_t len;
};

    struct cdev_key key = { 0 };
  if (rte_hash_add_key_data (testptr, &key,(void *) &test) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr,"add failed errno: %s\n", rte_strerror(rte_errno));
    }
```

and used in secondary as follows:

```
   printf("Looking for data\n");
   struct cdev_key key = { 0 };
   int ret = rte_hash_lookup_data (h,&key,&data);
```

Comment: Please add following details

Dpdk version
Build mode is static or shared
Primary and secondary application is single app
If primary & secondary is different are they having different .so or dlopen
Have ensured it is not pmap issue by using base-virtaddr??

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thanks for your reply, is there an easy way to check base-virtaddr? btw i did check the hash Pointer (h) and it is the same in both processes

Comment: you can use `pmap -x` and cross-check for rte_map virt address. If you feel suspicious use `--base-virtaddr 0x300000000000 `

Comment: @VipinVarghese Both rte_map are the same, but what changes in pmap is fbarray_memseg-* addresses and the address of our own dynamic DPDK libraries

Comment: Are there any updates?

Comment: @VipinVarghese Couldnt test it yet, will check it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

with DPDK version `19.02`, I am able to run 2 separate binaries without issues.

[EDIT-1] based on the update in the ticket, I am able to lookup hash entry added from primary in the secondary process.

```
Priamry log:
rte_hash_count 1 ret:val  0x0:0x0

Secondary log: 
 0x17fd61380 rte_hash_count 1
 rte_hash_count 1 key:val 0:0
```

note: if using `rte_hash_lookup` please remember to disable Linux ASLR via `echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`.

Binary 1: `modified example/skeleton` to create hash `test`
CMD-1:  `./build/basicfwd -l 5  -w 0000:08:00.1  --vdev=net_tap0 --socket-limit=2048,1 --file-prefix=test`

Binary 2: `modified helloworld` to lookup for hash `test`, else `assert`
CMD-2: `for i in {1..20000}; do du -kh /var/run/dpdk/; ./build/helloworld -l 6 --proc-type=secondary --log-level=3 --file-prefix=test; done`

Changing or removing the `file-prefix` results in assert logic to be hit.

note: DPDK 19.02 has the inherent bug which does not cleanup the `/var/run/dpdk/`; hence recommends to use `19.11.2 LTS`

Code-1:

```
        struct rte_hash_parameters test = {0};

        test.name = "test";
        test.entries = 32;
        test.key_len = sizeof(uint64_t);
        test.hash_func = rte_jhash;
        test.hash_func_init_val = 0;
        test.socket_id = 0;

        struct rte_hash *testptr = rte_hash_create(&test);
        if (testptr == NULL) {
                 rte_panic("Failed to create test hash, errno = %d\n", rte_errno);
        }
```

Code-2:

```
        assert(rte_hash_find_existing("test"));
        printf("hello from core %u::%p\n", lcore_id, rte_hash_find_existing("test"));
        printf("hello from core %u::%p\n", lcore_id, rte_hash_find_existing("test1"));
```

Comment: My issue is when looking up data from secondary: rte_hash_lookup_data (h,&key,&data);

Comment: Ticket opened with code snippet talks about not able to connect via secondary. The sample shared in the answer, showcases the secondary is able to connect without any issues. If you have a new issue, either update the ticket with a code snippet or open a new ticket.

Comment: @CharbelSemaan quick question, The sample code in the answer is using `rte_hash_find_existing`. It is working fine. Can you tell which API `rte_hash` in secondary is failing for you?

Comment: can you please try to lookup data in the secondary Hash: ret = rte_hash_lookup_data (h,name,&data);

Comment: please share the `key:value` that you have entered via primary. So that same 'key' can be used in secondary to lookup. Waiting for your update as you wanted to me check for you.

Comment: Updated the question, but you can add any key:value. tried multiple options with no luck. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @CharbelSemaan are using single binary with internal check for primary and secondary? or are you using 2 separate binaries. it works for me for both scenarios with the answer replied. So humble request, please be open for a live debug to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in DPDK Programmers Guide, using multiprocessor functionalities come with some restrictions. One of them is that the pointer to a function can not be shared between processes. As a result the hashing function is not available on the secondary process. The suggested work around is to the hashing part in the primary process and the secondary process accessing the hash table using the hash value instead of the key.

From DPDK Guide:

> To work around this issue, it is recommended that multi-process applications perform the hash calculations by directly calling the hashing function from the code and then using the rte_hash_add_with_hash()/rte_hash_lookup_with_hash() functions instead of the functions which do the hashing internally, such as rte_hash_add()/rte_hash_lookup().

Please refer to the guide for more information [36.3. Multi-process Limitations]

link: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/multi_proc_support.html

In the time of writing this answer the guide is for `DPDK 20.08`.

Comment: did this work on vanilla Linux (without ASLR disbaled). Can you share the snippet with DPDk 20.08? As I am not able to get this working with ASLR enabled on 20.08

Comment: @Farbord I hope you can share the working code snippet. With my internal testing this is not working. I have shared my findings to `maintainers` for DPDK hash too. So can you please share the working code snippet?